# Does Powerful Build apply to a goliath werebear's beast and hybrid forms?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, racial-traits, lycanthropy

I am playing a Goliath Barbarian and recently have contracted Lycanthropy of the Werebear variety.

According to the MM on page 207 it states that a character who becomes a lycanthrope retains their class statistics but I don't specifically see if it states that I can use my abilities while transformed. Maybe I've overlooked something.

My question is:

While shapechanged in Bear and Hybrid forms, does my Goliath ability Powerful Build still apply (also all other race/class abilities, i.e. Rage)? When transformed my size becomes Large; would I then count as Huge for all weight related rules, i.e. Carrying Capacity, Push, Lift, Drag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Ask your DM

Looking through the MM, PHB, DMG, errata, and twitter Q&A, I didn't really find any specific blurbs about this interaction except for the bit in the MM about "Nonhuman Lycanthropes" (p. 206):

> The statistics presented in this section assume a base creature of
>   human. However, you can also use the statistics to represent nonhuman
>   lycanthropes, adding verisimilitude by allowing a nonhuman lycanthrope
>   to retain one or more of its humanoid racial traits. For example, an elf werewolf might have the Fey Ancestry trait.

There is precedent for retaining *"features granted by your race, class, or other sources"* in the Druid's *Wild Shape*, but even then, it is limited to what the beast form is *"physically capable"* of doing.

If your DM allows you to retain your Powerful Build in Hybrid and Beast form, you would count as *huge* for carry capacity and push/lift/drag calculations.

Comment: Excellent! Can't believe I missed that little tidbit of information. This seems like exactly what I was looking for. This is going to make things interesting.